# ESP32 WebServer: How to get ip address of incoming clients

Tags: webserver, client, wifi, ip-address, esp32

With the help of [this tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-access-point-ap-web-server/) i created a simple WebServer on my ESP32:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

  IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(IP); //IP address of my ESP32
  
  server.begin();
}
```

```
void loop(){
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // If a new client connects
    Serial.println("New Client");           // print a message out in the serial port
    //...
  }
}
```

How to get the ip addess of this connecting client?^^ So thats maybe something there like

```
String ipaddress = /*...*/;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [`remoteIP`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientRemoteIP) returns the IP address as [IPAddress](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetIPAddress) object.

```
IPAddress ip = client.remoteIP();
```

IPAddress implements Printable so it can be used with println.

```
Serial.println(ip);
```

If you insist on getting the IP as String, the ESP32 core version of IPAddress has [toString](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/6b0114366baf986c155e8173ab7c22bc0c5fcedc/cores/esp32/IPAddress.h#L84) method.

```
String ipaddress = ip.toString();
```

There is no function to print the IPAddress object to characters array. You could use CStringBuilder class from my StreamLib to print the IPAddress to characters array. CStringBuilder allows to fill characters array with Arduino [Stream](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/) class functions. The StreamLib library is in Library Manager.

If you don't want to use the StreamLib library here is a (maybe not ideal) function to format the IPAddress to characters array.

```
void ip2str(const IPAddress& ip, char* s) {
  itoa(ip[0], s, 10);
  size_t l = strlen(s);
  s[l] = '.';
  itoa(ip[1], s + l + 1, 10);
  l = strlen(s);
  s[l] = '.';
  itoa(ip[2], s + l + 1, 10);
  l = strlen(s);
  s[l] = '.';
  itoa(ip[3], s + l + 1, 10);
}
```